# Apache2 not installing /etc/apache2 ubuntu 12.04

Tags: apache, ubuntu, apache2

I'm trying to recover from a recent problem upgrading to apache2.4 and php 5.5. I've uninstalled apache2 and deleted the `/etc/apache2` folder but when I install apache2.2 it's not creating `/etc/apache2` folder so doesn't start.

Answer (score 1):

Do as below:

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get remove apache2

sudo apt-get purge apache2

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install apache2
```

Answer (score 0):

Do as following

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge apache2 apache2-utils
sudo apt-get install --reinstall  apache2 apache2-utils
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, ive managed to reinstall apache2 but i can't downgrade PHP from PHP 5.5.9-1+sury.org~precise+1 to the normal PHP5.3

Comment: For downgrading this link may help. http://askubuntu.com/questions/396678/ubuntu-1310-downgrade-php-5-5-3-to-5-4